# Access Reports don't show up

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a Problem with my Access forms. I'm hiding the Access Database to the users with this code.

```
Const SW_HIDE = 0
 Const SW_NORMAL = 1

 Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" _
     (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long

 In der Öffnen-Sub deines Übersichtsformulares:

Dim hWindow As Long
 Dim nResult As Long
 Dim nCmdShow As Long
 hWindow = Application.hWndAccessApp
 nCmdShow = SW_HIDE
 nResult = ShowWindow(ByVal hWindow, ByVal nCmdShow)
 Call ShowWindow(Me.hWnd, SW_NORMAL)
```

But then i try to open the reports through my form they don't open. I don't know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never used that code, but it seems that the reason for your problem is described here in chapter 1.11: http://www.donkarl.com/FAQ/FAQ1Grundlagen.htm

(In the article there also is a link to a Microsoft article, but unfortunately also not in english)

> > Alle Formulare deiner Anwendung müssen auf Pop-Up eingestellt sein, weil sie sonst im nicht mehr sichtbaren Access-Fenster dargestellt werden und daher selber nicht mehr sichtbar sind. Beim Öffnen von Berichten in Seitenansicht muss man die (PopUP-)Formulare alle auf unsichtbar setzen oder schließen.

In english:

> > All forms of your application must be set to pop-up, because otherwise they will be displayed in the Access window which is no longer visible and are therefore no longer visible themselves. **When opening reports in page view you have to set all (PopUP-)forms to invisible or close them.**

You could give it a try.